# Discord.js - How to use <string>.replace() and replacing values?

Tags: node.js, regex, replace, discord.js

So, I asked a question earlier today and got an answer that sort of worked.
However, I don't quite know how to expand on the code...?

I have words in an array and select a random word from said array.
Single words, no spaces or special characters.

```
const words = [ 'energy',
    'oslo',
    'mother',
    'scanner',
    'summertime'
];
let num = getRandomInt(word.length-1);
let text = word[num];
let asterisc = conv(text); //this turns fex. summertime to - - - - - - - - - - 
// which is formatted for Discord: '**-** **-** **-** **-** **-** **-** **-** **-** **-** **-** '

/*
To try and convert back, I use:
*/

let reveal = revealChar(letter, text, asterisc);

//If the word was: business and I gave the letter e, I get: -e- - - - - - -
//It matches the e, but it's far from correct.
//I want: **-** **-** **-** **-** **-** **e** **-** **-** 

function conv(convert){
    let data = Array(convert.length+1).join('**-** ');
    return data;
}

function revealChar(chosenletter, original, asterisc){
    //This is the code I received from the first question, but I was not accurate enough in what I wanted to achieve.
    revealChars = asterisc.replace(/./g, (c, i) => original[i] === chosenletter ? chosenletter : c);
    return revealChars;
}
```

My code is sloppy (I'm just learning to code with Discord.js and Node.js), but everything is working like I want it to, except this "reveal" part...

Thanks a million in advance for taking the time to read, and maybe have a solution for me!

Comment: why not use an array of characters for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code I ended up using.
This returns the word in format, the way I was expecting.

```
function display(text, chars = [], format = char => `**${char === null ? "-" : char}**`, separator = " ") {
    const items = [];
    text.trim().split("").forEach(char => {
        items.push(format(chars.indexOf(char) == -1 ? null : char));
    });
    return items.join(separator);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its just a matter of *mapping* each letter to a character combination.
In this case the combination is `**-**`  which is a length of 6.
It ends up to find a position in the original string is to divide the
position by the factor, which is 6 in this case.

The easiest way to use a regex to do this since to change the format
just requires changing the string and using it's length to map to the original.

```js
// This converts example: 'summertime' formatted for Discord: '**-** **-** **-** **-** **-** **-** **-** **-** **-** **-** '

function conv(convert){
    let data = Array(convert.length+1).join('**-** ');
    return data;
}

// This reveals the selected letter in the Discord format.
// Note to map the asterisk for mat to the original word
// is to just use the offset which is a factor of 6 due to the length of '**-** '

function revealChar(chosenletter, original, asterisc){
    revealChars = asterisc.replace(/-/g, function(c, i) {
        let ndx = Math.floor(i/6);
        return original[ndx] === chosenletter ? chosenletter : c;}
       );
    return revealChars;
}

let text = 'energy';

let asterisc = conv(text); 
let reveal = revealChar('e', text, asterisc);

console.log( reveal );
```